# how to Repeat animation infinitely as a loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code to animate the line infinitely.
my html is somewhat like this.

```
<body>
    <div class="line_1"></div>
    <div class="line_2"></div>
    <div class="line_3"></div>
</body>
```

i have applied css like this..

```
body {
padding:50px;
}

.line_1 {
position:relative;

width:50px;
height:5px;
opacity:0.3;
background-color:#ef4646;
transform:rotate(-45deg);
transform-origin:left;
top: -10px;
left: 10px;
}

.line_2 {
position:relative;
width:50px;
height:5px;
opacity:0.3;
background-color:#86b4fc;
transform:rotate(45deg);
transform-origin:left;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}

.line_3 {
position:relative;
top:60px;
left: -40px;
width:50px;
height:5px;
opacity:0.3;
background-color:#f7e551;
transform:rotate(-45deg);
transform-origin:right;
}
```

and my script is somewhat like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.line_1').animate({ opacity:"1",left:"0px",top:"0px" });
            setInterval(function () { $('.line_2').animate({ opacity: "1", left: "0px", top: "0px" }); },400);
            setInterval(function () { $('.line_3').animate({ opacity: "1", left: "-10px", top: "30px" }); }, 600);

        });
    </script>
```

this animation applies only once when the page loads. but i want it to be repeated continuously.Kindly help me to do this.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0dowg5pf/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily wrap this into a function, and then use jQuery `animate`'s callback to call the function again. You also need to remove any applied styling, which I'll do by removing the `style` attribute from the elements. I also use jQuery's `delay` to delay execution of the animation.

I have also cleaned up your CSS, putting the shared elements in a shared rule, which makes your CSS much more manageable.

```js
function Animation(){
  $('.line_1').removeAttr("style").animate({ 
    opacity:"1",
    left:"0px",
    top:"0px" 
  });
  $('.line_2').removeAttr("style").delay(400).animate({ 
    opacity: "1", 
    left: "0px", 
    top: "0px"
  });
  $('.line_3').removeAttr("style").delay(600).animate({ 
    opacity: "1", 
    left: "-10px", 
    top: "30px" 
  }, Animation);
}
$(document).ready(Animation);
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
}

.line_1, .line_2, .line_3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform-origin:left;
}

.line_1 {
  background-color: #ef4646;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.line_2 {
  background-color: #86b4fc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.line_3 {
  top: 60px;
  left: -40px;
  background-color: #f7e551;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="line_1"></div>
    <div class="line_2"></div>
    <div class="line_3"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**--edit--**

you can do it with css. it's in my opinion a beter solution then using jquery.
i have use keyframes to animate it. and the `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` will make it animate infinite.
if you want it to go faster or slower, edit `animation-duration` to your preferred duration.

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
}

.line_1, .line_2, .line_3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform-origin:left;
}

.line_1 {
  background-color: #ef4646;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
 animation-name: line-1;
 -webkit-animation-name: line-1;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes line-1 {
  0%   {opacity:0.3; }
  30%  {opacity:0.3; left: 10px; top: -10px;}
  50%  {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
  100% {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes line-1 {
  0%   {opacity:0.3; }
  30%  {opacity:0.3; left: 10px; top: -10px;}
  50%  {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
  100% {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
} 

.line_2 {
  background-color: #86b4fc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
 animation-name: line-2;
 -webkit-animation-name: line-2;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes line-2 {
  0%   {opacity:0.3; }
  40%  {opacity:0.3; left: 10px; top: 10px;}
  60%  {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
  100% {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes line-2 {
  0%   {opacity:0.3; }
  40%  {opacity:0.3; left: 10px; top: 10px;}
  60%  {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
  100% {opacity:1; left: 0; top: 0;}
}

.line_3 {
  top: 60px;
  left: -40px;
  background-color: #f7e551;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: right;
 animation-name: line-3;
 -webkit-animation-name: line-3;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes line-3 {
  0%   {opacity:0.3; }
  50%  {opacity:0.3; left: -40px; top: 60px;}
  70%  {opacity:1; left: -10px; top: 30px;}
  100% {opacity:1; left: -10px; top: 30px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes line-3 {
  0%   {opacity:0.3; }
  50%  {opacity:0.3; left: -40px; top: 60px;}
  70%  {opacity:1; left: -10px; top: 30px;}
  100% {opacity:1; left: -10px; top: 30px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="line_1"></div>
<div class="line_2"></div>
<div class="line_3"></div>
```

Comment: I tried to use keyframes as well, but for this it is more complicated as they all need delays and correct lengths etc... It's possible but much harder. Your answer does not include any of the code given nor an implementation that works, nor the animation expected...

Comment: sorry im working on that. thought you want it to rotated but i will make it work. will post a edit shortly

Comment: It's not my question (: But there is already a basic implementation of the animation requested - ifytou check his code and run it you will see the animation requested (have a look in my post for a working snippet). If you can make it work in keyframes, I'll give you a +1.

Comment: haha sorry, didn't pay attention to the name. Thanks I will use it as a example.

Comment: @somethinghere i made it work. look at [codepen](http://codepen.io/motion_max/pen/Nxrzdm)

Comment: `line-3` seems incorrect in my Safari, but it is essentially correct! Stack Overflow provides their own snippets, which I would have preferred as it keeps the entire answer available for users on this site even if codepen would ever disappear. I have amended your post since it displays the code in exactly the same way but with a nice implementation added to it. Edit your post again to remove me as an editor (:

Comment: @somethinghere thanks for the feedback, I will look into that and tweak it a little and move the snippets (:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wrap everything in a function and call it in interval.

Working Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function startAnimation() {
    $('.line_1').animate({
      opacity: "1",
      left: "0px",
      top: "0px"
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.line_2').animate({
        opacity: "1",
        left: "0px",
        top: "0px"
      });
    }, 400);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.line_3').animate({
        opacity: "1",
        left: "-10px",
        top: "30px"
      });
    }, 600);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.line_1, .line_2, .line_3').removeAttr("style");
    }, 1600);

  }
  
  startAnimation();
  setInterval(startAnimation, 1650);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.line_1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: #ef4646;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.line_2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: #86b4fc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.line_3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: -40px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: #f7e551;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="line_1"></div>
  <div class="line_2"></div>
  <div class="line_3"></div>
</body>
```